# Roll commands in cog; discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "roll100"/"roll500" is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to code these 2 roll commands, I have random imported as well as choice imported so they should work. They are on a cog.

```py
    @commands.command(aliases=['roll500'])
    async def _roll500(self, ctx):
        n = random.randint(0,500)
        author = ctx.message.author

        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.green()
        )

        embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/762430826755260449/764946212527931392/die.png')
        embed.add_field(name='Roll', value=(f'Your random number is {n}/500.'), inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name="roll100")
    async def _roll100(self, ctx):
        n = random.randint(0,100)
        author = ctx.message.author

        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.green()
        )

        embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/762430826755260449/764946212527931392/die.png')
        embed.add_field(name='Roll', value=(f'Your random number is {n}/100.'), inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The error is; discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "roll100"/"roll500" is not found

Comment: What is your command prefix and what are you typing to the chat?

Comment: Prefix : dtog!
What I am typing: dtog!roll100/dtog!roll500

Comment: You're typing them in 2 other messages, right?

Comment: yes, I am typing dtog!roll100 in one message and dtog!roll500 in the other

Comment: But the command is `_roll100` so you have to type `dtog!_roll100` am I wrong?

Comment: Are other commands working? Do you have an `on_message` event? Do you have any checks?

Comment: @Nurqm his commands have aliases without the leading `_`

Comment: Do you have `on_message` event?

Comment: I think you did not load the Cog.